# Installing ROS on a tethered system

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a tank styled robot with an Odroid-N2 on the robot and a topside computer from which it's controlled BMO a joystick and web based GUI. Do I need to install Ubuntu and ROS on both controllers/computers?

Are there any versions of Ubuntu + ROS that are recommended for the above configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331302/installing-ros-on-a-tethered-system/) by [grantdutoit](https://answers.ros.org/users/45033/grantdutoit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johart24](https://answers.ros.org/users/77008/johart24/) on 2021-07-01**:
Hello, Did you use succesfully ROS with the Odroid -N2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the computer on top is only used for the web based GUI and the joystick, you could use something like [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) to send data from the topside computer to the Odroid via socket connections. Then, you won't need ROS on the topside computer.

However, if the system is tethered, I'd recommend to properly set up ROS on both computers, as this is an absolutely typical use case in ROS. Many robots consist of multiple computers. Make sure to follow the [NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) instructions and check out the links in there.
As this is a ROS feature that has been tied into it from the beginning, there is no recommended version to use other than choose an up-to-date distro like `melodic` (or at least `kinetic`, as this is still supported. `indigo` is EOL).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Esteban Castaño](https://answers.ros.org/users/77155/esteban-casta%C3%B1o/) on 2021-07-04**:
Hi everybody, if in this link https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-n2-with-4gbyte-ram-2/, it says that Ubuntu 20.04 is supported so, it means that can I install ROS noetic?